# Regex to extract first two octets of IP address in hive

Tags: regex, hive, rlike

I want to extract only first two octets of IP address in hive.
Can anybody please tell me equivalent Regex supported in Hive?

For example,extract '192.96.0.0' from ip_address '192.96.45.33'.

Comment: What does your data field look like? Not sure why you would need to use RLIKE, when you can just use like '192.96%'.

Answer (score 1):

```
192\\.96\\.\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}
```

Guess this should work as Hive uses `Java` format.

or

```
192\\.96\\.(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.)(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

Comment: Can anybody suggest  how to extract first two octets from ip address in hive. For IP '192.72.45.56' , i want to extract 192.72.0.0. How to achieve this?

Comment: @rupali you can extract `(?<!\\.)\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}\\.` this and append `0.0` later or you can use `replace` and replace `\\b\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}\\b(?!\\.)` with `0.0`.

Comment: select ip_address, regexp_replace(ip_address,'\\b\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}\\b(?!\\.)','0.0') as first_two_octet
from report limit 10;  I tried this query it is returning ip_address instead of first two octets. Sorry i dont understand regex much